# What is the zero in this transfer function?

Tags: transfer-function, zeros

What is the zero for the following transfer function, $-1/2$ or $-2$?

$$H(s) = \frac{2s +1}{(s + 3)(s + 2)}$$

This appears to give a zero of $-1/2$.

I can transform this into the standard form that includes the gain $K$:

$$H(s) = \frac 12 \left(\frac{s + 2}{(s + 3)(s + 2)}\right)$$

Where the leading half is the gain. The zero now appears to be $-2$. What is the conceptual error I am making? Should I take the gain out or leave it in the numerator?

**UPDATE**: I think this question is worthy of deletion given the nature of the error but I am unable to. Instead, see my answer below.

Comment: sometimes a “dumb questions” can be instructive

Answer (score 5):

$$2s+1=2\left(s+\frac12\right)$$
That's all I can say.

Comment: Oops, I think I’ll delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with a brain will realize I made an extremely elementary arithmetic error in my question. The transformed equation should of course be:

[image]

which means the zero is -1/2 as expected. The bottom line is that a gain has no effect on the values of the zeros since it is just a scaling factor in the zero polynomial.